# 'django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed:' error still showing after i have deleted the attribute

Tags: django

I was trying to add an attribute to a django model and it showed me **'django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed:'** error. So i backed down and just deleted the attribute, but it still shows me the error, so please how can i delete the attribute permanently.

The model(i have actually deleted the attribute from here).

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="blog_posts")
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    content= models.TextField()
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS, default=0)
    
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created_on']
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

The Error when i try to reverse the migration or carry out some other migration.

```
PS C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Tishas_Lifestyle> py manage.py migrate blog 0004
Operations to perform:
  Target specific migration: 0004_post_desc, from blog
Running migrations:
  Applying blog.0004_post_desc...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 413, 
in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
sqlite3.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: new__blog_post.desc

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
```

Comment: Did you add migrations? Did you make a new migration or go backwards and delete the migration?

Comment: also would be nice to see some code

Comment: I tried to delete  it using 'py manage.py migrate blog 0004'(blog is the name of the app). But then it gave me the error again.

Comment: I think i may need to do something like accessing the database directly and deleting that attribute(the table made for that attribute).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

when you deleted the new atttribute you added, you've got to cmd

```
py manage.py makemigrations
```

If it still doesn't work , try deleting your migration file or the entire database